# Segmentation fault core dumped...?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I'm trying to accomplish this:

> > Write a program that accepts three user inputs: assignment mark, midterm mark, and final exam
> >        mark.
> >
> > These inputs are of type float and should have values between 0 and 100.
> >
> > The program
> >       should compute the final grade as a percentage and a letter grade.
> >
> > • Final grades are computed as: Assignments 20%, Midterm 30%, Final exam 50%. Letter grades
> >        are computed as: A (final grade ≥ 80%), B (80 > final grade ≥ 70%), C (70 > final grade ≥ 60%),
> >             D (60 > final grade ≥ 50%), and F (50 > final grade).
> >
> > The final grade and letter grade are displayed.

with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int checkMark(int);
float getMark();
float computeFinalGrade(float assign, float midterm, float finalExam, float finalGrade);
int computeLetterGrade(float);

int checkMark(int x)
{
    while(x<0 || x>100) //While x is a negative number:
    {
        printf("Invalid entry.Try again:");
        scanf("%d",&x);
    }

    if(x>0 && x<=100)//If x is a positive number:
        x=x;

    return x;
}

float getMark(void)
{
    float mark=0,assignMark=0,midMark=0,examMark=0,finalMark=0;
    char letterGrade;


    printf("Enter assignment grade:");
    scanf("%d",mark);

    checkMark(mark);
    assignMark=mark;

    printf("\nEnter midterm mark:");
    scanf("%f",&mark);

    checkMark(mark);
    midMark=mark;

    printf("\nEnter exam mark:");
    scanf("%f",&mark);

    checkMark(mark);
    examMark=mark;


    finalMark=computeFinalGrade(assignMark,midMark,examMark,finalMark);
    letterGrade=computeLetterGrade(finalMark);

    printf("The final grade for the course is %.1f, and the letter grade is %c.\n",finalMark,letterGrade);

    return 0;
}

float computeFinalGrade(float assign, float midterm, float finalExam, float finalGrade)
{
    assign=(float)0.2*assign;
    midterm=(float)0.3*midterm;
    finalExam=(float)0.4*finalExam;

    finalGrade=(float)assign+midterm+finalExam;
    return finalGrade;
}

int computeLetterGrade(float finalGrade)
{
    int grade;

        if(finalGrade>=80)
            grade=65;

        if(finalGrade<80)
            if(finalGrade>=70)
                grade=66;

        if(finalGrade<70)
            if(finalGrade>=60)
                grade=67;

        if(finalGrade<60)
            if(finalGrade>=50)
                grade=68;

        if(finalGrade<50)
            grade=70;

    return grade;
}

int main()
{
    getMark();

    return 0;
}
```

When I debug the program above and enter a negative number it gives me this:

```
Enter assignment grade:123
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: Learn to use a debugger, such as http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/

Comment: Where does it crash? Load the core file into gdb and do some post mortem analysis. Then when you know a what line it crashes this topic is a little easier.

Comment: 123 is not a negative number...

Comment: @NickLH: I think it's "negative" as in _wrong_ in this case.

Comment: He says "and enter a negative number" i.e. number < 0 ...

Answer (score 5):

This is your problem:

```
scanf("%d",mark);
```

You need to pass *the address* of the variable, and the specifier should be `%f`. Try:

```
scanf("%f", &mark);
```

Incidentally, there is a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1.html) about this.

Comment: And that would have been caught by the compiler, if you compiled with `gcc -Wall -g yourcode.c -o yourprogram`. But you really should learn more!

Comment: You should learn how to use `gdb` and you should learn more about how to use `gcc`. In particular, you should always pass `-Wall`  to `gcc` for your code. You probably should also learn how to use `make` and write programs in several source files. Have fun.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How did you infer I don't know how to use `gdb` or that I don't compile with warnings enabled ?

Comment: Basile was probably talking about the OP, @cnicutar

Comment: Yes, the *you* referred to Iakam99, the person doing a homework.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux, take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316306/c-segmentation-fault-with-strcmp/7316492#7316492). It's about valgrind, a tool that helps debugging segfaults, memory leaks etc.

Answer (score 2):

Some more remarks on your code:

```
int checkMark(int x)
{
    while(x<0 || x>100) //While x is a negative number:
    {
        printf("Invalid entry.Try again:");
        scanf("%d",&x);
    }

    if(x>0 && x<=100)//If x is a positive number:
        x=x;

    return x;
}
```

should rather be:

```
#define MIN_GRADE 0
#define MAX_GRADE 100

int checkMark(int x)
{
    while(x<MIN_GRADE || x>MAX_GRADE)
    {
        printf("Invalid entry.Try again:");
        scanf("%d",&x);
    }

    return x;
}
```

Notice that I:

- removed useless comments
- removed magic numbers (0 and 100)
- removed a useless test (if you exit the while loop, then x is in {0, ..., 100}
- allowed `x` to be equal to 0
- removed an idempotent assignment (`x=x` doesn't do anything useful...)

Then:

```
float getMark(void)
{
    float mark=0,assignMark=0,midMark=0,examMark=0,finalMark=0;
    char letterGrade;

    printf("Enter assignment grade:");
    scanf("%d",mark);
```

^ As mentioned by others, you should use `%f` and `&mark` in this `scanf`.

```
    checkMark(mark);
```

^ Here, it should be `mark = checkMark(mark);` if you want the `mark` variable in this code to be updated. This is because the value of `mark` is passed to the function, not a reference to the variable `mark`. Another solution is to pass such a reference, but I don't think you're ready for this yet :)

```
    assignMark=mark;

    printf("\nEnter midterm mark:");
    scanf("%f",&mark);

    checkMark(mark);
    midMark=mark;

    printf("\nEnter exam mark:");
    scanf("%f",&mark);

    checkMark(mark);
    examMark=mark;
```

^ Same remarks for all these lines

```
    finalMark=computeFinalGrade(assignMark,midMark,examMark,finalMark);
```

^ Passing `finalMark` as a parameter here is completely useless. It should just be `finalMark = computeFinalGrade(assignMark, midMark, examMark);`, don't you think?

```
    letterGrade=computeLetterGrade(finalMark);

    printf("The final grade for the course is %.1f, and the letter grade is %c.\n",finalMark,letterGrade);

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned just earlier, you don't need to pass some `finalGrade` value to `computeFinalGrade`, you should be okay with just:

```
float computeFinalGrade(float assign, float midterm, float finalExam)
{
    return 0.2*assign + 0.3*midterm + 0.4*finalExam; // this could even be a macro
}
```

Finally, in `computeLetterGrade`, you are doing a lot of redundant tests, and your control flow is messed up by this variable assignment, plus you should use a `char` rather than an `int`. Try this instead:

```
char computeLetterGrade(float finalGrade)
{
    if(finalGrade>=80) return 'A';
    // Since we did not return, necessarily finalGrade < 80
    if(finalGrade>=70) return 'B';
    if(finalGrade>=60) return 'C';
    if(finalGrade>=50) return 'D';
    // All other ifs failed, therefore finalGrade < 50
    return 'E';
}
```

You will probably need to fix some things I didn't mention, but at least you should be closer to your goals with some of these corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation faults occur when your program tries to access a memory region outside the one assigned to your program. `scanf()` expects an address of the variable. In your code, you passed variable's value to `scanf()` instead of its address as pointed out by cnicutar.

```
scanf("%d",mark);
```

The mark variable is not initialized and has some random data, which is treated as a memory location by scanf and when it tries to write to that address... Segmentation fault occurs because you accessed a restricted memory. Also, mark is float variable and so you should use `%f` specifier..

```
scanf("%f", &mark);
```