# Segmentation fault after freeing completely different memory

Tags: c, memory-management, free

I have a monte carlo simulation, that is supposed to run multiple times and then average over the individual results. After each run, I want to free the allocated memory for the stuff I need in the simulation. One piece of this stuff is an array of `sites`, where each `site` is a struct that has a linked list of type `SLE` as one member. So in order to free all of it, I first iterate through the linked list and free each node and then free the memory of the `sites` array.

```
SLE * neighbor, * tmp;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < args.nsites_arg; ++i)
{
    // free neighbor memory
    neighbor = sites[i].neighbors;
    while(neighbor)
    {
        tmp = neighbor->next;
        free(neighbor);
        neighbor = tmp;
    }
}
free((void *)sites);
```

There is, however, something very weird happening: The simulation runs fine once and then starts over again. I reallocate all the needed memory for `sites` and rewrite the mentioned linked list of `SLEs`. Then, in some sorting operation on the former array, it gives mit a segfault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000408468 in sortNeighbors (list=0xad0e00) at mc_init.c:485
485         while(temp && temp->next)
```

When I remove the `free(neighbor)` in the above snippet, it works fine. As I said, everything is reallocated just like before the first run. So what happens here? How could I gather more information on what is really freed and why this segfault is happening?

---

Edit: The other weird thing is, that the beginning of this sorting looks like this:

```
if (!list || !list->next)
    return list;

SLE * temp = list;

// Find halfway through the list
while(temp && temp->next)
{
```

I explicitely check if `list` and `list->next` exist, so why is it giving a segfault in the while condition?

---

Edit2: The allocation

```
sites = (Site *) malloc(args.nsites_arg * sizeof (Site));
...
// s is now one element of the sites array
while(siteList)
{
    neighbors       = (SLE*) malloc(sizeof (SLE));
    ...
    neighbors->next = s->neighbors;
    s->neighbors    = neighbors;
    siteList = siteList->next;
}
```

Comment: I'm worried about that `(void *)sites` cast in your call to `free(3)` -- that typically means you forgot to include the `stdlib.h` header, and thus don't have access to the `free(3)` prototype.

Comment: How did you declare, allocate, and initialize `sites`?

Comment: You say you reallocate `sites` , but do you also set all the unused stuff to NULL - or otherwise ensure all the old stuff is gone/erased, so you're not touching dangling pointers anywhere ?

Comment: Can you run it in something like valgrind? It will hopefully give you more information.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisations disabled?

Comment: Hi sarnold, I indeed did not include stdlib.h, but including it doesn't help. And that cast shouldn't cause any problems, right?

I will attach a bit of the allocation to the question.

Comment: @nos: I guess I do, I initially set all elements to zero. Since I use malloc() I have to, even without having done anything before, since the memory could be full with garbage anyway.

Comment: @Joachim: I don't know much about it, but I will try to dig into valgrind a bit later.

Comment: @Oli: No, atm I don't use any optimization. (For I use -g)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: list (in the second snippet)

Comment: @jan: So what is the value of `list`?  Is it a valid pointer?

Comment: @janoliver "I explicitely check if list and list->next exist", which is good. But if you have only free()'d list or list->next , that check is not enough. free() doesn't set the pointers to NULL.

Comment: @nos That is a good hint. Thank you all for the tipps. Valgrind is broken on the Gentoo in my office for which I don't have root access, but I will try it at home.

Comment: @nos You were right with your first comment: I didn't set everything to zero after allocating. I read that there is calloc() that I could use instead of malloc(). I don't see it very often; why is that? Is it discouraged to use it? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux, take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316306/c-segmentation-fault-with-strcmp/7316492#7316492). It's about **valgrind**, a tool that helps debugging segfaults, memory leaks etc.

When you get SIGSEV by accessing freed memory (your case as I understand), it tells you where the memory was freed - it is not necessary that it was freed by the `free` call in your snippet.

Comment: I will try to dig into valigrind later. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Before searching for a bug, you might want to use an already implemented well tested [single or double linked lists](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-data-types.html).

Or, if you don't want to bother with the mem bug, link against [gc garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) (assuming the actual calculation of your simulation does what it should do)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I actually want to keep the dependencies as simple as possible and since I am still in the learning process of C, I would really like to find the problem and solve it myself. Plus, doing memory managment yourself makes you be more careful with it. As for the linked list: They consist of some big structs, so I think I will keep my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Some more good commercial tools for Windows:

- Purify
- Insure++

Answer (score 0):

Try running it through valgrind: `valgind --tool=memcheck [COMMAND]`

It works out of the box, nothing special needed.

For more info goto the [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.mcrun) website.