# C++ code crashes with "free(): invalid next size"

Tags: c++, free

I have written a small program which uses function pointers to do some numerical calculations.

```
double polynom(const int j, const double xi) {
  return pow(xi, j);
}

/**
 * Calculate the legendre_polynom l_end on a certain position xi.
 */
double legendre_polynom(const int l_end, const double xi) {
  vector <double> p_l(l_end+1);
  p_l[0] = 1.0;
  p_l[1] = xi;

  for (int x = 2; x <= l_end; x++) {
    // p_l = ((2x-1) * p_{x-1} - (x-1) * p_{x-2}) / l
    p_l[x] = ((2 * x - 1) * p_l[x - 1] - (x - 1) * p_l[x - 2]) / x;
  }

  double result = p_l[l_end];
  return result;
}
```

The program crashes with an unusual free() error. If I change the function pointer to the first function (polynom) it works fine, but it fails with legendre_polynom.

I already debugged that far that it breaks right after exiting that function and before the other code continues.

```
*** glibc detected *** blub: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0804f248 ***
======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6ebc2)[0xb7d70bc2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6f862)[0xb7d71862]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb7d7494d]
```

...

```
number2(_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIdE10deallocateEPdj+0x11)[0x804bc8b]
number2(_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIdSaIdEE13_M_deallocateEPdj+0x25)[0x804bbc3]
number2(_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIdSaIdEED1Ev+0x37)[0x804ba33]
number2(_ZNSt6vectorIdSaIdEED1Ev+0x38)[0x804b8a0]
number2(_Z16legendre_polynomid+0x13f)[0x804af9b]
```

So my question is what is wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Also, `l` is the worst variable name possible!

Comment: Maybe you should post your code that uses the function pointers...

Comment: have you tried running it through valgrind?

Comment: When you get a crash in free() or in delete, it usually means that memory has been corrupted. That can have happened any time before the call, anywhere in the program. So you need to show a more complete example.

Comment: I changed your counter variable from `l` to `x` so that we don't inadvertently summon Zalgo.

Comment: Try [valgrind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316306/c-segmentation-fault-with-strcmp/7316492#7316492)

Comment: Oh mean you are damn! fast thanks! I called this with l_max = 0, which is a valid call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no error in that code, provided that you always call that function with `l_end >= 1`.

When `l_end == 0` instead there is an out of boundary write operation in `p_l[1] = xi;`.

Note however that you cannot infer that this is the function having the problem just because this is where you get a crash or just because not calling this function you have no crash.

An error is an error and a crash is a crash. They are completely distinct in C++; the sooner you realize this important fact the better. There may be an error somewhere else and this function may be just the victim.

If you see a crash then there is an error. If you see no crash you know nothing (the error may be still present).

Comment: This made it. Huge thanks. Will approve the answer once my limit is down.