# weird segmentation fault

Tags: c++

What I have been doing is a reverse polish notation calculator.I have met this error when compiling my program below:

```
class Expression {
       protected:
                 string exp;
                 int value;
       public:
                 void getExp();//extract the exp from Expression
                 void setExp(string s);//store s in Expression
                 void setValue(int n);//store n in Expression
                 int evaluate();//extract the value from Expression
 };


 ...
 class binary : public Expression {
  public:
          void binaryyy(Expression *x1,Expression *x2,string op){
             if(op=="+"){
                 setValue(x1->evaluate()+x2->evaluate());
                 string x;
                 x.append(x2->getExp());
                 x.append("+");
                 x.append(x1->getExp());
                 setExp(x);
                }
             else if(op=="-"){
                 setValue(x1->evaluate()-x2->evaluate());
                 string x;
                 x.append(x2->getExp());
                 x.append("-");
                 x.append(x1->getExp());
                 setExp(x);
                }
             }
 };
```

then in my main function:

```
 int main(){
  ...
  Expression *stack[10];
  int p=9,i;//p refers to one slot above the top element of the stack
  for(i=0;i<10;i++) stack[i]=NULL;
  ...
  string s_input;
  getline(cin,s_input);
  istringstream sss(s_input);

  while(!sss.eof() && p>-2){
  sss>>s;
  if(s=="+" || s=="-")
     binary *b = new binary;
     b->binary(stack[p+1],stack[p+2],s);
     stack[p+1]=NULL;
     stack[p+2]=b;
     p++;
  }
  else if(s.isNumber())//s.isNumber() might not exist.it means that s is number...
  {
     Expression *c=new Expression;
     istringstream ss(s);
     int temp;
     ss>>temp;
     c->setValue(temp);
     stack[p]=c;
     p--;
  }
  }
  ...
```

I have checked very carefully for any possible illegal allocation or call of memory slots and all.NO CLUE...

PLUS:p would not overrun in this case.

Comment: you mean the segfault happens while compiling, not running your program? otherwise, what is the stack trace at the moment of the crash?

Comment: it happened when running program.

Comment: `gdb` is your friend. Learning to use it is kinda important if you're going to debug C or C++

Comment: Sequence of `Expression`s caused segfault might help to understand issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int p=9,i;//p refers to the top of the stack

...

b->binary(stack[p+1],stack[p+2],s);
stack[p+1]=NULL;
stack[p+2]=b;
```

Well there is an overrun.  `stack[p+1]` is `stack[10]` and `stack[p+2]` is `stack[11]` in your ten element array.  You're writing past the bounds of your array (unless the `...` contains code which adjusts `p` correctly, but I have no way to know).

After that problem is fixed you need to initialize your `stack` array.  Currently you have an array of 10 pointer to `Expression`.  None of them are initialized to point to anything valid though, and you later dereference them.

Also...

```
b->binary(...)
```

Won't compile.

Comment: I have edited my post.Then you could see that p would not overrun.

Comment: Er, no ... it's doing exactly what @EdS. is telling you.

Comment: @y26jin: I don't see that at all; I see the same obvious overrun.  You are corrupting your stack, from there on out anything could happen.  You need to fix that.

Comment: @y26jin: You also need to initialize the pointers in your `stack` array. Currently they are all invalid, yet you dereference them when passed to your `binmaryyy` function.

Comment: @Ed S. It is actually my bad that I didnt include my code thoroughly but p did not overrun. suppose we have "1 2 +" as input,then 1 and 2 will be pushed into stack and when it comes to "+" both 1 and 2 will be popped out,plus and pushed back as a binary object in stack.in this process,p value changes from 9->8->7.This code could output correct answer but exist segmentation fault caught by valgrind

Comment: @y26jin: I still see nowhere in your example where you modify `p` after declaring it and initializing it to `9` *before* using `p+1` and `p+2` to index into the array.  *This is a bug and is invoking undefined behavior*.  I also added an edit to point out that you are dereferencing uninitialized pointers in your `stack` array.  That is another possible cause of the segfault.

Comment: @Ed S. if the input is a number,then there is a "p--" as a last step of pushing a number into stack.in terms of uninitialization,I think it is possible...gimme a sec :-)

Comment: @y26jin: If `if(s=="+" || s=="-")` evaluates to true the first or second time around your code fails.  Also, again, your array is full of uninitialized pointers. If the first input is a number you still have a bug because you decrement p, but index to `p+1` if the next input is an operator.  Same problem.  Also, this `stack[p]=c;` is not sufficient to initialize your array as you can easily access uninitialized pointers around `stack[p]` after entering a number.  The code is very fragile and is not correct even when used with 'correct' input (i.e., 1 + 2).

Answer (score 1):

First, compile with all warnings enabled and with debugging information produced. On Linux, that means `g++ -Wall -g`.

Then, learn to use the debugger (on Linux, `gdb` or a graphical front-end like `ddd`).

Answer (score 0):

`stack` can hold 10 pointers to `Expression`s, i.e., from index 0 to 9. The stack pointer `p` starts from 9, but in your code, you say stack[p+1] and stack[p+2], both of which are examples of illegal indexing(They respectively translate to stack[10] and stack[11], which are nonexistent).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux, take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316306/c-segmentation-fault-with-strcmp/7316492#7316492). It is about [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), a tool that can help you debug runtime problems.