# Getting Segmentation Fault with string Heap Sort code in C++

Tags: c++, string, sorting, segmentation-fault, heapsort

```
int heapSize = 20; //variable 
int left(int i) {
return (2 * i) + 1;
}

int right(int i) {
return (2 * i) + 2;
}

void heapify(string arr[], int i) {
int l = left(i);
int great=0;
int r = right(i);
if ( ((strcmp(arr[l].c_str(),arr[i].c_str()))>0) && (l < heapSize)) {
great = l;
}
else {
great = i;
}

if ( ((strcmp(arr[r].c_str(),arr[great].c_str()))>0) && (r < heapSize)) {
great = r;
}
if (great != i) {
string temp = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[great];
arr[great] = temp;
heapify(arr, great); //Getting segment here 
}

}

void BuildMaxHeap(string arr[]) {
for (int i = (heapSize - 1) / 2; i >= 0; i--) {
heapify(arr, i);
}
}

void HeapSort(string arr[]) {
BuildMaxHeap(arr); //
for (int i = heapSize; i > 0; i--) {
string temp = arr[0];
arr[0] = arr[heapSize - 1];
arr[heapSize - 1] = temp;
heapSize = heapSize - 1;
heapify(arr, 0);
}

}
```

Getting segmentation fault with this string heap sort code for heapSize larger than 15, for example 20 elements.
Any idea about the reason?

I backtraced it in gdb and I get this

```
#0  0x0038124b in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#1  0x08048f62 in heapify(std::string*, int) ()
#2  0x08049050 in heapify(std::string*, int) ()
#3  0x080490ae in BuildMaxHeap(std::string*) ()
#4  0x080490d3 in HeapSort(std::string*) ()
#5  0x080494f5 in main ()
```

So, what is wrong with the heapify function?

Comment: Err... why are you using `strcmp` on C++ strings??? Whatever happened to `<`/`==`/`>`?

Comment: You are most likely reading beyond the bounds of your arrays. Simply put breakpoints and check those array indices.

Comment: I am using > or < instead but nothing change

Comment: I dont think that it is about the bounds of the array cause it works with other sorting algorithms!

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it is correct and will work always. Codes exhibiting Undefined Behaviors bite you when it matters the most.

Comment: If you are on linux, try [valgrind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316306/c-segmentation-fault-with-strcmp/7316492#7316492)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `if`s you should check if the indexes are in the bounds of the array *before* you try to compare the stings:

```
if ( (l < heapSize) && (arr[l] > arr[great]) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It is your array indexes.  Check out the `left` & `right` functions and the for loop parameters that feed them.  With an odd numbered 'heapSize' value `left` will eventually return an index past the end of the array.  With an even numbered 'heapSize', `right` will do it.

e.g.
when 'heapSize' == 15, then the max 'i' passed to 'heapify' will be 7 *((15-1) / 2)*.  Pass that into 'left' and you get 15.  Too big for the array, so it croaks when trying to get the string for the 'strcmp'.

Maybe I've done something wrong, but I'm not getting your code to run regardless of heap size.

PS. build with '-g3' flag to get better debug symbols in gdb. `g++ -g3 heap.cc`