# Segmentation Fault when getting user input

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have this:

```
    // Get database access parameters 
    const char* db = "codes", *server = "localhost", *user = "root", *pass = "pass";

    // Connect to the sample database.
    mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
    if (conn.connect(db, server, user, pass)) {

        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
            int d, count;
            cout << "Введите D\n";
            cin >> d;
            cout << "Введите количество записей при D=" << d << endl;
            cin >> count;
            for (int a=0; a<count; ++a)
            {
                char * name;
                int r,n1,n2;
                cout << "Введите R\n";
                cin >> r;
                cout <<"Введите n1 и n2\n";
                cin >> n1 >> n2;
                cout <<"Введите название\n";
                cin >> name;
                mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query();
                for (int j=n2-n1+1; j<n2; ++j)
                {
                    int k =pow(2,(j+r));
                    query << "insert into code (n,k,d, name) values (" << j << "," << k << "," <<d<<"," << mysqlpp::quote_only << name << ");";
                    query.execute(); 
                }
            }
        }
        conn.disconnect ();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "DB connection failed: " << conn.error() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Sorry for posting all the code.
I can compile the program with no errors, but in command line, it says "Segmentation fault". Whats this error? And how to solve it?

Comment: You should make your next quest learning to use a debugger, for example gdb. A debugger would have told you that you're crashing in the `cin >> name;` line and that `name` is not a sane pointer.

Comment: If you are on linux, try [valgrind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316306/c-segmentation-fault-with-strcmp/7316492#7316492)

Answer (score 7):

You should allocate space for

```
char * name;
```

before writing to it.

If you know that name isn't going to be longer then MAXNAME then just define name to be

```
char name[MAXNAME+1]
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanx.And, one more thing, I can't into syntax highlighting, whats the matter?

Comment: @АйкСаркисян You managed it by yourself!:) If you find the answer to be satisfying, please consider accepting it.

Comment: *If* you actually recommend char arrays in C++, please *do* show how to avoid buffer overflows. `char name[MAXNAME+1]` does *not* solve problems, it just hides them until the assumption that there are no longer names doesn't hold anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I see that you are using C++. In this case, you should use

```
std::string name;
```

so you **don't have to** allocate space for it.

Rule of thumb: If you're using C++, use `<string>` instead of `char[]`; use `<vector>` instead of arrays; use member variables initialized by constructors instead of *either* `malloc()` *or* `new()`. It will make your coding life easier, believe me.

(Every rule has its exceptions, but that's the starting point...)

Comment: Yeah, I've changed it to string, char seems to be hardcore.

Comment: @АйкСаркисян Keep in mind that string goodies come not for free, but with performance penalty. If you can neglect it, of course use string.

Comment: @RomanB.: An urban legend that has hurt many a C++ project, because people believed it and wrote half-baked, bug-ridden C-style code instead. If you are afraid of the resizing, add `name.reserve(MAXNAME+1);`. When Knuth uttered his words about premature optimization, he meant exactly this case. **Prove** that C++ strings are the performance bottleneck before coding a `char[]`. Everything else is just shoddy workmanship. I've seen many projects that were hurt by char buffer overflows, but not a single one that was hurt by proper use of `std::string`.

Comment: @DevSolar Here is the proof: http://www.d-programming-language.org/cppstrings.html See tables in the bottom.

Comment: @RomanB.: Does apply to the OP's question... how? Neither does he code in D, nor is the type of `name` critical to the performance of his program.

Comment: @DevSolar You have given GENERAL recommendation. I have given GENERAL precaution. Discussion must end at this point.

Comment: @RomanB.: I object to the notion that anyone must be able to "neglect the performance penalty" of C++ strings in order to use them. (You have to prove them being the bottleneck before optimizing them away.) I object to telling C++ beginners to use `char [MAXSIZE];` without even *telling* them about `std::string`, or even `fgets()`. I object to developers jeopardizing stability and maintainability of an application by listening to hearsay. I object to people linking to a biased D-vs-C++ paper in order to make a C-vs-C++ point. I object to you telling me where a discussion should end or not.

Comment: @DevSolar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5405/discussion-between-roman-b-and-devsolar)