# Segmentation fault in loading multiple images using loops

Tags: c, opencv, segmentation-fault

I am trying to load multiple images in this code. This code below does not show any syntax error, however, when run, it shows segmentation fault right away. It doesn't even print the "Try!" statement above. What must be causing it's segmentation fault because in my other programs, sprintf worked perfectly? Thank you!

```
int main () {
IplImage *image = 0, *srcCopy = 0;
int w, h, i, j, r, g, b, index;
CvScalar pixel, pixOut;
char ifilename[50], ofilename[50];

 //LOADS IMAGE
for(index=0; index<3; index++){
    printf("Try!");
    sprintf(ifilename, "data set baybayin/%d.jpg", index);
    image = cvLoadImage(ifilename, 1);

    w = image->width;
    h = image->height;

    srcCopy = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++) { 
            pixel = cvGet2D(image, i, j);
            b = pixel.val[0];
            if (b > 50)
                pixOut.val[0] = 255;
            else
                pixOut.val[0] = 0;
            cvSet2D(srcCopy, i, j, pixOut);
        }
    }

skeletonize(srcCopy);
sprintf(ofilename, "preproc/preproc%4d", index);
cvSaveImage(ofilename, srcCopy);

cvReleaseImage(&image);
cvReleaseImage(&srcCopy);
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Why is your `return 0;` inside the `for` loop?

Comment: I noticed that the segmentation fault starts at this line: w = image->width;
What seems to be the problem about the image being accessed?

Comment: Can `cvLoadImage()` return NULL?

Comment: I'm not so sure but I think the image is not loaded properly?

Comment: First of all, when you are debugging, **always** put `'\n'` after the debugging output. The `printf` function has a line buffer, so when you don't print `'\n'`, your debug print stays in the internal buffer. And try [valgring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316306/c-segmentation-fault-with-strcmp/7316492#7316492)

Comment: @cmsl Review your other questions and accept some answers. I know a couple of them have been successfully answered!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `cvLoadImage` expects a filename as its first argument but you're passing in the string `"data set baybayin/`*index*`.jpg"`.  Try dropping the `"data set in "` part.

`stdout` is likely buffered.  If the segfault occurs before the buffer fills, you may not see all output.  This is probably the reason why you're not seeing `Try!`.

Comment: i tried doing what you said but it still produces segfault starting from the line w=image->width. Perhaps the problem is that the image is not loaded properly? However, i'm not sure what to do to fix that.

Comment: Check `if (NULL != image)` prior to accessing `image` to avoid segfault. Does `cvLoadImage()` provide a reason for failure?

Comment: If there's something wrong with the file itself, then there's probably not much you can do to fix it in this code.  If `cvLoadImage` returns a `NULL` pointer in that case then you can check for that and skip such bad files.

Comment: It returns NULL so there's something wrong with loading the image.

Comment: Does it return `NULL` for all three images?  What about for an image you manually create with, say, `gimp`?