# this pointer is lost when calling a member method

Tags: c++, g++, x86-64

I have encountered a strange problem when compiling my program using 64-bit g++ 4.7.0  on a Fedora 17 x86_64 machine (the same program works well on a 32-bit Fedora).

The program is too complicated and I cannot figure out an easy way to produce a small code sample. But from the following gdb record, you can see the problem.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000042a4b0 in boost::shared_ptr<cppPNML::details::ddObj>::operator!(this=0x100000007)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/operator_bool.hpp:55
55          return px == 0;
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install gnome-keyring-3.4.1-3.fc17.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000042a4b0 in boost::shared_ptr<cppPNML::details::ddObj>::operator! (this=0x100000007)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/operator_bool.hpp:55
#1  0x00000000004202a5 in cppPNML::pnNode::getBBox (this=0xffffffff) at cpp_pnml.cpp:131
#2  0x000000000040eca4 in draw_page (g=..., painter=...) at pnml2pdf.cpp:178
#3  0x000000000040e3b9 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe188) at pnml2pdf.cpp:106
(gdb) up
#1  0x00000000004202a5 in cppPNML::pnNode::getBBox (this=0xffffffff) at cpp_pnml.cpp:131
131   if(!p_) return pair<double, double>(0,0);
(gdb) up
#2  0x000000000040eca4 in draw_page (g=..., painter=...) at pnml2pdf.cpp:178
178     boost::tie(w, h) = node.getBBox();
(gdb) p node
$1 = {<cppPNML::pnObj> = {_vptr.pnObj = 0x79a490, p_ = {px = 0x7c40a0, pn = {pi_ = 0x7c4170}}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) l
173   QRectF bound(0,0,0,0);
174   
175   // nodes
176   for(pnNode node = g.front<pnNode>(); node.valid(); node = node.next()) {
177     double h, w, x, y, wa, ha, xa, ya, angle;
178     boost::tie(w, h) = node.getBBox();
179     angle = atan2(h, w);
180     boost::tie(x, y) = node.getPosition();
181     wa = 0; ha = 0; xa = 0; ya = 0;
182     
(gdb)
```

The program under debugging is a graphic printing program (pnml2pdf) that draw a graph to pdf using QT4.
The object node belongs to class pnNode, which is defined by my own graphic data struct library (quite complex, https://github.com/wsong83/cppPNML).
It is shown a SEG error where the smart pointer is uninitialized.
Through the back trace you can see that the this pointer of node.getBBox() is invalid.
However, printing the node from one level upper show the node is actually OK.

I am totally confused here.

Anyone has any clue or need any more code segment? Thanks in advance!

Update:
Thanks to the advice from @atzz, I am now certain the calculation of this pointer in member method getBBox() produced a wrong address. The problem is not caused by any source code error (directly linking object files will eliminate the segment fault), but caused by the 64-bit static library generation command "ar" (as the definition of pnNode is defined in a static lib rather than object file). It is seems now the static library is wrong and causes the wrong this calculation.

Still digging... Will update the result if anyone is still interested to know.

Comment: I think reducing your problem to a manageablely sized sample will help you to find your problem and us to understand what goes wrong here. That dump from gdb isn't that helpful.

Comment: Wah, already get a down vote. No objection to @honk comment, but believe me, if I can do it without too much trouble, I must had done so. Please do not simply blame before doing anything helpful.

Comment: have you tried valgrind?

Comment: Is it reproducible when stepping through the code in debugger? I looked at the sources and this behavior definitely looks weird..

Comment: @Dadam the same error. Would you share more about your reasoning to use valgrind, memory leak, or simply tring another debugger, or any specific valgrind options to run with valgrind?

Comment: @WeiSong: Try to look at it from our pov. We know almost nothing about your program. Not what the functions we see do, what the types involved are, what the members all look like etc. Try reading what you gave us, but replace all the names of your functions and types by gibbersih. Then you can see what we see. You weren't able to solve the problem with all information, how should we with just a tiny fraction? All we can do is guessing wildly and maybe hit the reason. Or not. But either way, it is not a good question for SO as it is now.

Comment: Can you post disassembly for lines 176..179 above, and also for the `getBBox` member function?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I disagree. The code is linked in the question, and it's not too big to look through. Definitely this question appears to be very narrow, but the underlying problem could be general enough to benefit others (we don't know yet). I think the existing trend of bashing questions which are not immediately understandable is detrimental to the future of SO as a useful resource.

Comment: @atzz I have post the step debugging info in the question edited. node.valid() is fine, but getBBox() is not. I also want to see the disassembly my self, but how can I do it? sorry, I have never gone to this detail before.

Comment: You can get disassembly in gdb via `disassemble` command. If my memory does not fail me, `disass pnml2pdf.cpp:176 pnml2pdf.cpp:179` should disassemble the range of addresses corresponding to the mentioned lines.

Comment: @WeiSong it is a linux debugger specialized for solving memory-related problems. You can take a look at [quick start](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.interpret) or at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316306/c-segmentation-fault-with-strcmp/7316492#7316492)

Comment: @atzz and Dadam , thank you both for your help. I am now in office where is the 32-bit machine. Again, the exact code runs well on 32-bit Fedora 14. I will try disassemble and valgrind tonight.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is this an optimised build or a debug build? Looks to me like it should be failing on line 176 not line 178.
2. Are you sure the loop is right? Looks like you are going over the end. I suspect your implementation of `node.valid()` either doesn't do the right thing, or is the wrong thing for the loop test.

The value `0xffffffff` looks like a `std::iterator` `end()` value so I think you either need to test your loop against that, or make sure the `pnObj::valid() const { return p_ != NULL && p_ != 0xffffffff; }`

Also the way you are implementing `next()` just looks wrong. Creating an iterator, searching for the string ID and then calling `next()` on the iterator?

Comment: Er, I have doubted line 176 before, but from the step debugging you can see the valid() member method indeed gets the right this pointer. I will try to write a simple program to test the loop, hopefully I have made some silly errors there.

Comment: Also, this is not iterator. next simply return the next node object. The same way is used in other light-weighted graphic library such as OGDF. Implementation iteration type is good but may be heavier than what is needed (so not implemented yet).